# Do we want to do the Winter Bash again this year?

Tags: discussion

Although it is usually up to the site moderators to decide if we want to participate, I figured the whole community should have some input.

From the Community Team:

> As another year draws to a close, we wanted to do something fun and
>   lighthearted with our communities, as a way of celebrating the many
>   amazing people who make the sites awesome. So, we’re announcing Winter
>   Bash 2013!
>
> Most of you probably remember last year’s event, but I’ll recap
>   anyway, for the newbies among us. Winter Bash is an annual event that
>   can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users
>   earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous
>   to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which
>   their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats
>   in a leaderboard that looks something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Winter Bash 2013 will again be available to all sites that choose to
>   participate. We’re redesigning the landing page and redesigning all
>   the hats to keep things fresh and exciting.
>
> Some Details
>
> This event will run from **16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014**. Users
>   will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
>   That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and
>   other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats
>   will go back into storage**.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
>   the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So, what do you think? Should Pro Webmasters participate again this year?

Comment: I think it is a resounding yes.  John, can you fill out the form to opt our site into this?

Comment: Done. We will have hats!!!! (and scarves, pipes, mustaches....)

Answer (score 4):

Definitely!!!! I missed out on last years! and besides! it only comes once a year :P

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be fun. Personally, I want the cool glasses again!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It sounds fun!  I need some hats on my icon.

Answer (score 2):

Let me put my thinking cap on first...sure, why not  <|:-)

Answer (score 2):

Oh yes - bring it on! ;)

[image: Christmas Hats 2012 - League Tables]

<sub>(Dang, is it that time of year already?!)</sub>